# How to keep upstream and fork synced after erroneous PR

Tags: git, github, git-pull, pull-request

I have forked a repository and I am working in a few contributions. I have made an erroneous PR and after close it I can't get both repos: `upstream` and `fork` synced. I have read how to sync a fork [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) but seems to be not working for me since after run every command and close the PR I still not getting the latest code. See the pic below:

[image]

How do I fix this? How I can reset the fork to the original state without the PR and my changes? (yes I can loose them since it's a few lines and I can write them again in case it's mandatory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not commit the content of your pull requests to your fork's master. Instead, create a new branch for every pull request and don't add anything to master instead of the original project's commits.

TL;DR: Delete your fork and fork again

Manual way:

- Go to a local checkout of your fork
- `git checkout master` just in case you are somewhere else
- Use `gitk` or `git log` to find the last commit id of the original repository, let's call it `e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e`
- `git reset --hard e5fa44f2b31` This cuts and removes everything after `e5fa44f2b31`
- `git push --force` This pushes the cutting to Github. You need `--force` because you're manipulating history. Don't do that with branches that other people rely on.
- Now you should only have commits of the upstream repository in your fork (see `gitk` and Github again)
- [Locally add a second remote called "upstream"](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/)
- [Get the latest changes from upstream into your master](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)
- Never commit custom changes to a fork's master again ;)